# DateTime.TryParse issue with dates consisting of a.m instead of am

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following date in string format "2017-04-05 05:00:00 a.m" . Now I am trying to convert that to datetime format with the following code:

```
var dateTime="2017-04-05 05:00:00 a.m";
DateTime value = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParse(dateTime, out value );
```

But I am alwayws getting dt as {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM} , Can you please tell me why ? and how can I convert that string to date.

Comment: Check the return value from TryParse, it could be telling you it failed.

Comment: No it is not returning any thing , it is getting me 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM this value

Comment: have you tried to use `TryParseExact`.

Comment: TryParse returns a boolean of success/fail ... you arent testing that - hence my point, check the return value

Answer (score 12):

You could try creating a custom `DateTimeFormatInfo` with your custom am/pm designators:

```
var formatInfo = (DateTimeFormatInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.Clone();
formatInfo.AMDesignator = "a.m";
formatInfo.PMDesignator = "p.m";

var value = DateTime.Parse("2017-04-05 05:00:00 a.m", formatInfo);
```

This also works for afternoon times:

```
var value = DateTime.Parse("2017-04-05 03:00:00 p.m", formatInfo);
```

Comment: @Joe this is working fine , if possible can you explain me the answer

Comment: @Meena - when parsing the string, DateTime.Parse and related methods will expect an AM/PM designator that matches the `DateTimeFormatInfo` being used to parse.  By default, this will be taken from Thread.CurrentCulture, and English cultures will expect the strings "AM" and "PM".  Your strings contain "a.m" and "p.m", which don't match any known culture as far as I know, but you can create a custom `DateTimeFormatInfo` as shown with your custom am/pm designators.

Comment: @Meena Not sure why I'm complaining, but did you mean to accept [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43229207/590382) and not Joe's answer? I think this one is probably the better way to do it since this way will still work with fractional seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The `DateTime` string you have is not parsed and you are getting the default value. One of the reason is the a.m in your date string. It also depends on Current [thread Culture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx) settings as well. You can use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) to give the format you have in DateTime string also with [CulureInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss 'a.m'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out value);
```

Note you have a.m instead of am which has to be escaped like I did with 'a.m' in above example.

You can have p.m as well and above wont work for that. You can replace dot with empty string to make `a.m` to `am` and `p.m` to `pm` to use [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) `tt` for am / pm. *I assume there would be only one dot between `am` or `pm`*.

```
string dateTime = "2017-04-05 05:00:00 a.m";
dateTime = dateTime.Replace(".", ""); 
DateTime value = DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out value);
```

Read more about impact of [Thread.CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The CultureInfo object that is returned by this property, together
>   with its associated objects, determine the default format for dates,
>   times, numbers, currency values, the sorting order of text, casing
>   conventions, and string comparisons. See the CultureInfo class to
>   learn about culture names and identifiers, the differences between
>   invariant, neutral, and specific cultures, and the way culture
>   information affects threads and application domains. See the
>   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property to learn how a thread's default
>   culture is determined, and how users set culture information for their
>   computers.

Comment: what happens if it actually is `p.m`...?

Comment: even i had the same doubt

Comment: @DanielA.White, we can change a.m and p.m to am, pm and mentioned in answer.

Comment: @Meena, I tried to clear your doubt, let me know if you still have it?

Answer (score 0):

The `.` in `a.m` is causing the problem. Assuming that you have both `a.m` and `p.m` to deal with, try stripping the `.` characters before you try to parse the `DateTime` value.

```
var stringToParse = "2017-04-05 05:00:00 a.m";

DateTime parsedValue;
DateTime.TryParse(stringToParse.Replace(".", string.Empty), out parsedValue);
```

This will not work if a `.` character is used elsewhere in the string, for any other reason. Fractional seconds for example. If that is the case, you'd be better off using [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229215/590382) instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White Hi Daniel, I see you've given a similar comment to many other answers. Could you expand on _why_? It would be more helpful.

Comment: you shouldn't rely on replacing a string like that - it assumes too much.

Comment: @DanielA.White That's true, it does assume the input data is always going to be in a particular format, but since that format was specified in the question it's not a completely unreasonable assumption.

Comment: Though I do think @Joe's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43229215/590382) is the best one so far.

Comment: @Ben Jenkinson, your answer and Joe answer worked fine for me. Thats the reason to accept both of your answers.

Comment: @Meena I'm glad it helped :) though there [can only be one 'accepted' answer per question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/can-i-accept-two-answers) ([+15 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)); but you can upvote as many useful answers as you like (+10 rep)

Comment: Yeah i know , i upvoted your answer and also accepted it.